# Using singleton for caching

Tags: c#, caching, singleton

I recently read that singleton is an anti-pattern and should not be used unless it is really needed.

In all our projects, we use the singleton pattern to hold some cache data. For example:

```
class SomeClass
{
   public SomeClass()
   {
       var somedata = Singleton.Instance.GetSomeData(stringRepresintation); // or like that
       var someData = Singleton.Instance.SomeData;
   }      
}
```

What is the recommended design to hold that data (static class, or something else)?

Comment: may be you need it in you rprojects

Comment: you might wanna take a look at dependency injection libraries like Autofac..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could think of the cache as a dependency - and pass an instance (probably the same instance) into everything which needed it. That's what I'd do in a situation where I was already using dependency injection.

That would make it easier to test those classes which need the cache - you could create a new cache for each test, and not have to worry about clearing out an existing one. You could also parallelize tests without worrying about two tests messing up each others caches. Additionally, it makes the cache dependency clearer.

(Whether or not you use an interface to represent the cache as cdhowie suggests is up to you. You don't *have* to, although it would decouple the classes from their dependencies more if you did. If your cache is very simple and you don't mind using the production implementation in tests, it *may* not be worth extracting an interface.)

Comment: in a new project, what is your recommendation ?

Comment: @guyl: I'd use dependency injection as described above. Depending on the size of the project, you may or may not want to use an IOC container to help you - sometimes it can be simpler to create everything up-front programmatically; you can still make all the relevant classes use DI.

Answer (score 4):

You would create some `ICache` interface that defines the members necessary for a cache provider.  Then you would allow an instance to be passed in to `SomeClass()`.  You can still use a default instance (implementing `ICache`) if the caller doesn't specify one.  This is the dependency injection pattern, which is essentially the complete opposite of the singleton pattern.

This will allow a different caching mechanism (or just different cache instances) to be substituted in without any changes to `SomeClass`.

Comment: Wouldnt you add the class as a single instance to the resolver, eg it would effectively be retrieved as a singleton wrapped in whatever DI framework you are using?